# requires your app to be migrated to the Android embedding v2. ......how to solve this problem?

Tags: flutter, dart, github, flutter-dependencies

it keeps says me that
requires your app to be migrated to the Android embedding v2. Follow the steps on
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects

Comment: You're getting an option with instructions on how to solve the problem. Yet you ask how to solve the problem?

Comment: the page gives 404 error

Answer (score 6):

Note....its the same as following this steps
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects
but i made it easier for any one that cant follow the steps .....hope that helped.

After trying multiple ways to deal with the situation,

I ended up with a good enough solution

just open this files in your project and copy >> paste this lines of code and it will work .......make sure to delete all lines of code in your this files and replace it to this new ones.

1: MainActivity.java

---

package co.appbrewery.flash_chat;

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {

}

---

2: styles.xml

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

---

3: AndroidManifest.xml

---

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
   package="co.appbrewery.flash_chat">  
<!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
     calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
     In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
     additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
     FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
<application android:label="flash_chat" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
             until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
             there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
             defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
        <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable" android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="flutterEmbedding" android:value="2" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

---

Answer (score 2):

Follow the steps. Hopefully, your problem will be solved. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects

Comment: yes thank you .......i just put an answer that make it easier for any one than follow this steps ........thinking that maybe could be helped any one than following the steps.

Comment: It's Okay. Then you should give an upvote for my suggestion. :)